# How to change background URI in Roku channel?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I'm new to Roku channel development and last week I started creating a Roku channel. I want to change the background URI, when the user selects a row item the channel thumbnail should be set as the background URI. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the background image set then all you need it's just to find that node by id (if there is no id then set it in XML) and update the URI when you want (based on some observer or key press if it's just for test).

E.g:

SomeComponent.xml

```
...
 <Poster id="background" uri="pkg:/images/background_hd.png" width="1280" height="720" />
```

SomeComponent.brs

```
sub init()
  m.background = m.top.findNode("background")
  ...
end sub
```

then based on key press or some observer you could set a new URI:

```
m.background.uri = "new URI"
```

Here is documentation about the `Poster` and how `observers` work:
https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/references/scenegraph/renderable-nodes/poster.md

https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/developer-program/core-concepts/handling-application-events.md#handling-node-field-value-changes

Also, I think it will be useful to review those samples to get better understanding on how the things work on Roku:
https://github.com/rokudev/samples